# Express: passing options to an included server

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to develop an Express website that can run either stand-alone or as part of a larger server while allowing a degree of configuration.

For example, say I have a large main server in `server.js` and I write another server `app.js` that defines a route `/*` to provide a small service. I want to be able to either:

- run `app.js` standalone, which will provide its routes through `localhost:port/`
- define a route within `server.js` that maps to this server, for example so that `/app/*` will allow `app.js` to handle requests.

Reading through *Smashing Node*, I see that if I define an Express server and its routes in `app.js`, I can use: `server.use('/app', require('app.js')` to gain use of its routes. The problem with this approach is that I do not see how to pass any configuration options to `app.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your **app.js** module as a callable function:

```
var express = require("express");

var app; // <-- note the global

var initialize = function(conf) {
    if (app) {
        return app;
    }

    conf = conf || {};

    app = express();

    // here goes the configutation code, for example:
    if (conf.static) {
        app.use(express.static(conf.static));
    }
    return app;
};

if (require.main === module) {
    // if standalone, fire it
    initialize({ static: __dirname + "/public" });
}

// and export
module.exports = exports = initialize;
```

and then in other file:

```
var app = require("app.js")({ static: __dirname + "/public" });
```

Note that it is a singleton, so further calls to the module function will return the same server:

```
app == require("app.js")();
```

I'm sure you can tweak it to your needs.

Comment: I didn't mention it in my question nor is it relevant to my use case, but it seems like the fact that this is a singleton might render this a less than optimal solution. It doesn't seem like an esoteric use case to want to be able to require multiple instances of the same service at different routes using different options--I think an ideal solution would allow that. But I'm marking this as solved as this fulfills the original question.